# Remove username field registration form - Woocommerce

Tags: php, html, woocommerce

How can I remove the username field in the registration form in woocommerce?

I tried to remove some line from the **woocommerce/myaccount/login-form.php**

```
<?php if ('no' === get_option( 'woocommerce_registration_generate_username' ) ) : ?>

<p class="form-row form-row-wide">
<input type="text" class="customer_login_input" name="username" id="reg_username" placeholder="User name" value="<?php if ( ! empty( $_POST['username'] ) ) echo esc_attr( $_POST['username'] ); ?>" />
</p>
<?php endif; ?>
```

After that the field doesnt appear in the page, but when I enter the e-mail and the password to register some new account I get the following error: **Error: Please enter a valid account ID.**

I guess, delete this line brok somethings in the registration form..

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: And what will you use for the username? Without a username, users will not be able to login to the site.

Comment: I want that they can login with the e-mail and the password,
It's not possible to do like that ?

Comment: Sorry, I mean, I want that they can register only with the necessity of the user field and the e-mail field.
But I thinks that we should do lots of thinks to do that.

Comment: What version of WooCommerce are you using? The error message you posted seems to point to something else, it says "Account ID" , if the username was not present it should say "Username", so not sure if your theme is doing something different.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Navigate to `WooCommerce -> Settings -> Accounts` tab, scroll down to "Account Creation" section and tick the checkbox for "*Automatically generate username from customer email*", save your settings.

You've already removed the username field from your registration form, now things should work as expected. Upon registration WooCommerce will derive the username from the email field by splitting it on @ symbol.

So if someone registers with john@example.com , the username will be john . If an existing user with the same username is found, username will be changed to john1.

**EDIT**  (thank you @helgatheviking)

As Kathy has pointed out, you can also use the following [plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-email-login/)

P.S: if you are using an older version of the plugin then the option to automatically generate username from email may not be available.

Comment: Something like [this plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-email-login/) might also help.

Comment: I agree with you, most certainly it will, and I was going to recommend it. However the functionality OP is trying to achieve is available in WooCommerce core. Its my personal preference to not depend on an external plugin.

Comment: Awesome! It's just what I needed.
Thanks you mate :)

Comment: Always happy to help :) Happy coding.

Comment: Cool, I don't think I realized that it was in WC core. In that case, you're probably right in not needing a 2nd plugin to duplicate the same functionality.

Answer (score 2):

Remove username field registration form - A solution for those who only need the email when registering for woocommerce

Can you make sure these checkboxes within WooCommerce > Settings > Accounts & Privacy are disabled?

[image]